# Angular 4 Karma testing error

Tags: angular, testing, karma-runner

I want to make `Karma` tests on my `Angular 4` application. When I leave the tests simple without importing anything they succeed. For example:

```
describe('Sample test', () => {
    it('should pass', () => {
        expect(1 + 1).toBe(2);
    });
});
```

However, when I try to import a class which is in the same folder like so:

```
import { ApiResponseTimeRepository } from './ApiResponseTimeRepository';
```

I get an error saying:

```
Chrome 58.0.3029 (Windows 10 0.0.0) ERROR
  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
  at services/TestRepositories.spec.ts:1
```

For reference, my class looks like this:

```
...
imports
...

@Injectable()
export class ApiResponseTimeRepository {
    ...
    code
    ...
}
```

And here is `karma.conf.js` :

```
// Karma configuration
// Generated on Mon Jun 12 2017 14:21:41 GMT+0200 (Central European Daylight Time)

module.exports = function (config) {
    config.set({

        // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
        basePath: 'src/app',


        // frameworks to use
        // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
        frameworks: ['jasmine'],


        // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
        files: [
            { pattern: '**/*.spec.ts' }
        ],


        // list of files to exclude
        exclude: [
        ],


        // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
        // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
        preprocessors: {
        },


        // test results reporter to use
        // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
        // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
        reporters: ['progress'],


        // web server port
        port: 9876,


        // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
        colors: true,


        // level of logging
        // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


        // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
        autoWatch: true,


        // start these browsers
        // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
        browsers: ['Chrome'],


        // Continuous Integration mode
        // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
        singleRun: false,

        // Concurrency level
        // how many browser should be started simultaneous
        concurrency: Infinity,

        mime: {
            'text/x-typescript': ['ts', 'tsx']
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: You need to compile your ts files bevor you can test them. JS doesn't know the import keyword

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: take a look how the angular-cli does it

Comment: I don't see how that will help me implement it in Karma testing environment? Even if I knew it inside out I still need to somehow implement it with Karma and I still don't know how to do it?

Comment: You can generate a new project and copy the karma config

Comment: But how will that make my current project work?

Comment: You can set up your testing environment like the cli does

Comment: It didn't work.